# Quiero hacer DELETE a un elemento seleccionado while

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo un sistema de carrito en mi sitio web, no tengo ningun problema para insertar los productos en el, para sumar sus precios, el problema me surge cuando quiero borrar los productos. No quiero vaciar todo el carrito, quiero que cada producto tenga su boton para eliminar y solo se elimine el producto seleccionado. Traigo mis productos con un while, ya que tengo los items del carrito en una base de datos, y cada producto que el usuario ingresa ya genera su boton para eliminar. El problema es que no importa en cual boton de eliminar haga click, me vacia el carrito. Debe ser un problema en la sentencia, ya que la eliminación la esta haciendo sin problemas. De todas formas aclaro, probe exactamente la misma sentencia que estoy usando en mi PHP directamente en mi base de datos y me borro exactamente el libro que yo le pedia, pero mediante php no me esta funcionando. Les dejo codigo y espero puedan ayudarme, muchisimas gracias!
[image: Codigo problema]

Comment: Debes copiarlo en formato de código para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Sería mejor que pegases el texto del código y no una imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El botón de borrado no hace referencia a la id del elemento, debería ser algo como:

```
<button type="submit" name="eliminar" value="<?=$row['idOrdenes']?>"></button>
```

Así cada botón envía el id del elemento y lo capturas con:

```
  if ($_POST['eliminar']) {
      $id_eliminar = intval($_POST['eliminar']);
      .....
  }
```

por ejemplo.

Comment: GENIO! Muchas gracias!